# Moving bullet points

Tags: shortcut-keys

In LibreOffice Writer, I used to be able to move bulleted lines very conveniently up or down in my list by holding down alt-cntrl while hitting the up or down cursor movement keys. I was surprised to find this function when I did--by accident--and did something to make it disappear. Anyone know how to get it back?

Comment: For as long as I can remember CNTRL+ALT+(UP/DOWM/LEFT/RIGHT)ARROW  moved the current desktop between different virtual desktops. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

On the Writer's menu select Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard. Under "Shortcut keys" select "ctrl+Alt+Down". Under Functions/Category select "Edit" and under Functions/Function select "Move Down". Finally, select Writer on the right (if not already selected) and press "Modify". Repeat the same steps for "Move Down".

Comment: @user68128. I tested it on a KDE based desktop and worked OK. On a **Linux Mint 18.3** (Ubuntu 16.04) and an **Ubuntu 17.10** computer the behavior is as you describe, but that's no problem. You can assign it to `Alt+Shift+Up/Down`. This worked OK on **Linux Mint** and **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Thanks. In Customize menu, I see the proper command assigned to ctrl-alt up and  down, keys, but it fails to work. Maybe it's the keyboard. I'll keep messing with this.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on a KDE based desktop and worked OK. On a Linux Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04) and an Ubuntu 17.10 computer the behavior is as you describe, but that's no problem. You can assign it to Alt+Shift+Up/Down. This worked on Linux Mint and Ubuntu.